# In Windows Workflow Foundation, do custom activity/workflow classes have to be sealed?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I notice that the default Visual Studio template for a workflow, and really all the code samples I've found online, declare it as `sealed`. What if I want to create another activity/workflow based on a previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use WF and none of our custom code activities are sealed.